# Robocopy wont copy folders with a dot at the start

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, file-permissions, robocopy

I'm trying to use robocopy to copy some files to a network drive. Here's the command I am using:

`robocopy /Z /E /R:10 /W:30 /tee /ETA H:\ "\cloud\backup-leon\The Flash\Data" /XD "Temp" "Temporary Internet Files" /XF pagefile.sys hiberfil.sys /log:"\cloud\backup-leon\The Flash\log.txt"`

The problem is that it skips all files beginning with a `.`, e.g. `.bin`. Is there any way to allow robocopy to copy these types of files?

Comment: What is your exact command?

Comment: Install bash for Windows 10 and use Linux :p

Comment: Is it reporting errors for these dot files during the copy? Tested filenames beginning with . and they copy fine for me.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I have been able to use the same command that you posted in your question and it works for me. Manually created files using PowerShell (New-Item ..\.bin) and it still copies successfully. If there are error messages saved in the logs, please post them.

Comment: I intermittently hit something like this copying from my local machine to a freenas machine with a CIFS share when there is already a file of the same name (starting with a dot) at the destination. I'm the only one copying to the share, via the same script every time. I'll get access denied errors when robocopy tries to copy the file starting with a dot. I've yet to reliably reproduce it, but when it happens, deleting the file fixes it. I realize that's not terribly helpful, but you're not the only one seeing wonkiness with robocopy/network shares and dotted file names...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other mentioned in the comments `robocopy` doesn't have any problems with that files that start with a dot, I made a test with several files and directories that start with a dot using the same parameters that you and it copied them without any problem.

Since that files are mean to be hidden in Linux some multi-platform programs mark that files as hidden to achieve the same behavior in Linux and Windows, so I tried marking that files as hidden and `robocopy` also copied them.

So I have two theories:

- The problem is related with file permissions, you should check the log to see if there are any problems when accessing that files.
- The files are indeed marked and hidden and since robocopy maintain that attribute you don't see the hidden files in the destination for some reason (the `\cloud\` in the destination folder makes me thing that it's not a regular folder).